# java.lang.NullPointerException in the program

Tags: java

I am keep on getting following error in my program. There is nothing wrong with any syntext or any errors also

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at PresentationLayer.AdminLogin.btnLoginActionPerformed(AdminLogin.java:155)
    at PresentationLayer.AdminLogin.access$000(AdminLogin.java:11)
    at PresentationLayer.AdminLogin$1.actionPerformed(AdminLogin.java:51)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
```

This is my java code

```
private void btnLoginActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

        String username = txtUsername.getText();
        Admin itemObjUserName = new Admin().getLoginDetailsDB(username);

        boolean found = (itemObjUserName.getUserName()).equalsIgnoreCase(txtUsername.getText()) && (itemObjUserName.getPassword()).equalsIgnoreCase(txtPassword.getText());
        if (found == true) {
            String message = "Welcome to the City Library Management System";
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, message);
            AdminMenu Obj = new AdminMenu();
            Obj.setVisible(true);
            this.dispose();

        } else {          
            if (count < 2) {
               count = count +1 ;
                if (count == 1) {
                    String message1 = "Invalid  Password.!.Warning 2 more Attempts left";
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, message1);
                } else if (count == 2) {
                    String message2 = "Invalid  Password.!.Warning 1 more Attempt left";
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, message2);
                } 
            } else {

                    String message3 = "Invalid Password.! & You are Temporarily Blocked for Exceeding Max Number of Login Attempts.Error";
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, message3);
                    txtUsername.setVisible(false);
                    txtPassword.setVisible(false);  
                    btnLogin.setVisible(false);
            }
        }
    }
```

I would be thankful if anyone could help me with this

Comment: The error is line 155, set a breakpoint there and check which object is null. Then determine why it is null.

Comment: @Sala 

line 155 is this 
(itemObjUserName.getUserName()).equalsIgnoreCase(txtUsername.getText()) && (itemObjUserName.getPassword()).equalsIgnoreCase(txtPassword.getText()); if (found == true)

Comment: then one of `itemObjUserName, txtUsername and txtPassword` has a `null` value, use a break point and debug which one is `null`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a reference (say `x`) on line 155 which is null and you're calling `x.someMethod` or `x.someField` on it. Check line 155 and see what is `null` there.

Comment: thanks for your comment.  this is what in line 154 and 155

 boolean found (itemObjUserName.getUserName()).equalsIgnoreCase(txtUsername.getText()) && (itemObjUserName.getPassword()).equalsIgnoreCase(txtPassword.getText());
        if (found == true) {  

so i have the problem with when user enters the wrong user name and password 
but according to the code i have written it is supposed to check the wrong user name and password for 3 times

Comment: Then... one of these is probably `null`, check them: `itemObjUserName, txtUsername, txtPassword`.

Comment: selected login details successfully m getting to the itemObjUser according to the entered txtUserName. so theres no null values in those itemObjUserName, txtUsername and txtPassword ..

Answer (score 0):

As indicated above by peter.petrov add a validation before the declaration of boolean found.

```
  //declare variable
    boolean found = false;
  //verify that all elements are not null (and maybe not empty - it applies to getText() property)
    if(itemObjUserName != null && itemObjUserName.getUserName() != null && txtUsername != null 
&& txtUsername.getText() != null && itemObjUserName.getPassword() != null 
&& txtPassword != null && txtPassword.getText() != null)
   {
     found = ...
   }
```